# Lambda expression in java 8 (Null check in HashMap using java.util.Optional)

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

I'm new to java 8 and learning lambda expression.

I have an interface.

Configuration.java

```
package com.raghu.example;

import java.util.Map;


public interface Configuration {

    public Map<String,String> getPayload();

}
```

Impl for interface: ConfigurationImpl.java

```
package com.raghu.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ConfigurationImpl implements Configuration {

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getPayload() {
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("key1", "value1");
        map.put("key2", "value2");
        //return null;
        return map;
    }

}
```

My Main Program : Sample.java

```
package com.raghu.example;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Sample {

    Configuration config;

    /*
     * if config is null, return "";
     * if config.getPaylaod is null, return "";
     * if config.payload is not null and if key value is present, then return the value
     * if config.payload is not null and if invalid key, then return "";
     * 
     */

    String test(String key) {
        config = new ConfigurationImpl();
        String dataValue = "";

        /** java 7 
       if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(key)) {
            try {
                String input= config.getPayload()==null?"":config.getPayloadmap().get(key);
                return (input!=null?input:"");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return "";
    }**/
        Optional.ofNullable(config).map(Configuration::getPayload).ifPresent(v->{final String str=v.get(key);System.out.println(str);});
//        //cdataValue=str;});
//        //Optional.ofNullable(config).map(Configuration::getPayload).ifPresent(v->{final String str=v.get(key);System.out.println(str);return str;});
       return dataValue;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Sample s = new Sample();
       String value="";
       value=s.test("key"); //pass invalid , should return "";
       System.out.println(value);
       value=s.test("key1"); //pass invalid , should return actual value
       System.out.println(value);
    }

}
```

Now in the method test, i want to do the following[""].

1. Check if config is null, return empty String.
2. Check if collection is null, return empty string.
3. If collection is not null, and if key is present, then return the value else return "";

How to do this in java 8?

Tried this:

1. Error 1:Void methods cannot return a value

   ```
   Optional.ofNullable(config).map(Configuration::getPayload).ifPresent(v->{final String str=v.get(key);System.out.println(str);return str;});
   ```
2. Error 2: Local variable dataValue defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final.

   ```
   Optional.ofNullable(config).map(Configuration::getPayload).ifPresent(v->{final String str=v.get(key);System.out.println(str);dataValue= str;});
   ```

Adding final doesn't solve.

Also posted the java 7 code and I'm trying to solve the if-else part of java 7 with lambda expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just keep on chaining `.map(...)`.  If null happens at any of the steps, it will just make the whole thing into an empty `Optional` and then `orElse("")` will return the default value.

```
return Optional.ofNullable(config)
        .map(Configuration::getPayload)
        .map(c->c.get(key))
        .orElse("");
```

Comment: `c->c.get(key)` can be replaced with `Map::get(key)` :)

Comment: @Clashsoft, didn't work for me..      return Optional.ofNullable(config)
                      .map(Configuration::getPayload)
                      .map(Map::get(key))
                      .orElse("");    am i missing something here?

Comment: @Clashsoft I don't believe there's such a thing as `Map::get(key)`.  Method references cannot take arguments.

Comment: My bad - that is indeed not possible. Although this is a pointless limitation, as there is no technical reason this couldn't work

Comment: @Clashsoft: it’s the other way round: there is no reason to support a second syntax to express the same thing. `c->c.get(key)` perfectly describes the operation.

Comment: Yes there is: performance. `c->c.get(key)` creates a temporary `lambda$x` method in your class, with a signature like this `(Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;` - but we already have a non-specialized version of this `java/util/Map.get(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;`. This way, we have a double indirection and another method in the class file.

Comment: @Clashsoft I think you meant `c::get`, i.e. `map(c::get)`.